# Is it possible to store a partial View ID in a variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm wondering if it's possible to store a partial View ID in a variable.
For example: If I would have two Views, one with the ID `food_pizza` and a second one with the id `food_burger`, could I store `"pizza"` and `"burger"` in a variable as a string and then access both Views through `R.id.("food_" + VARIABLE)` and `R.id.("food_" + VARIABLE)`.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: that is possible, but why do you need it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's probably not the best way to do it but I want to display some stats for the past week, past month, etc and thought it might declutter the code.

Comment: @Slimez it looks rather dirty and confusing in mu opinion as well, I think it would be cleaner to set custom tags to views and use `findViewByTag` instead.

Comment: @Pawel It's definately a dirty solution, I'll look into a more advanced solution when I have the time. :) I'll definately check out tags, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you would want to do it, but here you go :)

`int id = getResources().getIdentifier("food_" + VARIABLE, "id", getPackageName());`

Comment: This is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible like this R.id.("food_" + VARIABLE)

You can try this alternative way:

Create `HashMap<String, Integer> ids = new HashMap<>();`

Then add ids to map with keys like `food_pizza` etc

```
ids.put("food_pizza", R.id.food_pizza);
ids.put("food_burger", R.id.food_burger);
```

and to use it you get ids like `findViewById(ids.get("food_" + VARIABLE));`

Comment: Thanks! That might be a better alternative! :)

Comment: Not possible like this `R.id.("food_" + VARIABLE)` :)